# MySQL updating "link" table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table `users` and a table `salesmen`.
I want to assign salesmen to users. One salesmen can be linked to multiple users.

So I made a `users_salesmen` "linking" table with the colums `user_id` and `salesmen_id`.

I have a page where I can link them

```
       | Salesemen 1|  Salesmen 2 | Salesmen 3 |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
User 1 | checkbox   |  checkbox   | checkbox   |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
User 2 | checkbox   |  checkbox   | checkbox   |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
User 3 | checkbox   |  checkbox   | checkbox   |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
```

The checkbox is in HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_id[6][]" value="3" />
```

Where the value is the `salesmen_id`

An example of how the could be linked:

```
       | Salesemen 1|  Salesmen 2 | Salesmen 3 |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
User 1 |     x      |             |     x      |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
User 2 |            |     x       |            |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
User 3 |            |     x       |     x      |
-------|------------|-------------|------------|
```

Which would result in a the `users_salesmen`

```
salesmen_id  |   user_id
------------ |------------
    1        |     1
    2        |     2
    2        |     3
    3        |     1
    3        |     3
```

So my question is, how do I update the table after I made some  changes.
I've always did:

- delete all rows in `users_salesmen`
- loop the inputs, those who are checked get inserted in `users_salesmen`

Is this the right way, or is there a better way of updating the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating checkbox lists is a pain, but the easiest/cleanest method is basically what you're doing:

```
start transaction
delete old stored checkbox data
insert all checkboxes from form
commit transaction
```

Otherwise, you're stuck with getting the old list, comparing it to the new list, and building up separate insert/delete queries to delete any "unchecked" boxes and insert any "checked" ones.

It's easier to just nuke everything old and insert everything new. The transaction guarantees you end up with a consistent result at the end, and hides the deletions/insertions from other parallel code up until you actually commit.

Answer (score 1):

You say that "One salesmen can be linked to multiple users.". If this is true and the opposite is NOT true ("one user can be linked to multiple salesmen") then the following is a good solution.

Have a 'salesman_id' column in your users table, and simply add the salesman id to the relevant users row. Your salesmen table will then simply have the salesman details and their id - the users table will contain the id of the salesman assigned to them. Each salesman could have several users assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @MarcB that your is the best approach. Anyway, just for discussion purpose I can suggest you another way that is with array_diff to get only what to add and what to remove:

```
function array_diff_ORG_NEW(&$org, &$new, $type){
    switch($type){
        case 'VALUES':
            $int = array_values(array_intersect($org, $new)); //C = A ^ B
            $org = array_values(array_diff($org, $int)); //A' = A - C
            $new= array_values(array_diff($new, $int)); //B' = B - C
            break;
        case 'KEYS':
            $int = array_values(array_intersect_key($org, $new)); //C = A ^ B
            $org = array_values(array_diff_key($org, $int)); //A' = A - C
            $new= array_values(array_diff_key($new, $int)); //B' = B - C
            break;
    }
}
```

This will look at both the keys or the values and will provide you all the items that are to be added or removed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have accepted Marc B's answer, but gave you a +1 for the effort! Nice alternative!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your procedure is a feasible one. Because, if you are allowed to update only row (in your HTML) in UI , that means you are allowed to update data only for a single user at a time. So, on that time you should only delete and reinsert data for that user only, other should remain same.
But if you are allowed to modify more than user's record at a single call, then you have to delete all the records of that link(map) table and reinsert them.